# How to get the data from UCI machine learning repository

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a small problem with reading the [data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/image/) from this source correctly. I tried to write:

```
path = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/image/segmentation.data'
df = pd.read_table(path)
```

[And then I got something strange.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYx2r.png)

Then I wrote:

```
df = pd.read_table(path, sep=',', header=None)
```

and got an error: `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 19`

Could you, please, help me to find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

The file is basically a `csv` file so you can use `read_csv`. Use it in combination with `skiprows=2` to skip the first non-relevant rows of the file.

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/image/segmentation.data'
df = pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=2, index_col=False)
```

Output `df.head()`:

|  | REGION-CENTROID-COL | REGION-CENTROID-ROW | REGION-PIXEL-COUNT | SHORT-LINE-DENSITY-5 | SHORT-LINE-DENSITY-2 | VEDGE-MEAN | VEDGE-SD | HEDGE-MEAN | HEDGE-SD | INTENSITY-MEAN | RAWRED-MEAN | RAWBLUE-MEAN | RAWGREEN-MEAN | EXRED-MEAN | EXBLUE-MEAN | EXGREEN-MEAN | VALUE-MEAN | SATURATION-MEAN | HUE-MEAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | BRICKFACE | 140 | 125 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0.277778 | 0.062963 | 0.666667 | 0.311111 | 6.18518 | 7.33333 | 7.66667 | 3.55556 | 3.44444 | 4.44444 | -7.88889 | 7.77778 | 0.545635 |
| 1 | BRICKFACE | 188 | 133 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0.333333 | 0.266667 | 0.5 | 0.0777777 | 6.66667 | 8.33333 | 7.77778 | 3.88889 | 5 | 3.33333 | -8.33333 | 8.44444 | 0.53858 |
| 2 | BRICKFACE | 105 | 139 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0.277778 | 0.107407 | 0.833333 | 0.522222 | 6.11111 | 7.55556 | 7.22222 | 3.55556 | 4.33333 | 3.33333 | -7.66667 | 7.55556 | 0.532628 |
| 3 | BRICKFACE | 34 | 137 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0.5 | 0.166667 | 1.11111 | 0.474074 | 5.85185 | 7.77778 | 6.44444 | 3.33333 | 5.77778 | 1.77778 | -7.55556 | 7.77778 | 0.573633 |
| 4 | BRICKFACE | 39 | 111 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0.722222 | 0.374074 | 0.888889 | 0.429629 | 6.03704 | 7 | 7.66667 | 3.44444 | 2.88889 | 4.88889 | -7.77778 | 7.88889 | 0.562919 |

Answer (score 0):

Can you give encoding like this:

```
path = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/image/segmentation.data'
df = pd.read_csv(path,encoding = 'utf8')
```

If it does not work, can you try other encodings?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the data file contains some meta information that Pandas cannot parse. You need to convert your file to a CSV before it can be read by `pandas`.

To do this, first download the file to your local machine at some location `filepath` and remove the lines starting with the `;;;` and the empty lines. Then running a `pd.read_table(filepath, sep='\t')` or a `pd.read_csv(filepath)` should work as expected.

Note that the `header` argument does not refer to any generic header information that the file may contain. `header` lets `pandas` know whether the first line in your CSV contains the names of the columns (if `header` is `True`) or whether the actual data in the file starts from the first line (if `header` is `False`).

Comment: RJ Adriaansen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66945438/13945013) gives a more elegant way to skip the redundant first two lines than manually removing them.